# Why doesn't uniqueness of Taylor series need orthogonality of the polynomials?

Tags: taylor-expansion, orthogonality

As I know the inner production of x^n and x^m is not zero. Then how is it possible for the series to be unique?

Comment: Linear independence is sufficient for the series to be unique, no need in orthogonality.

Comment: This subtlety is related to the fact that Weierstrass's theorem can hold even though not every continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is real-analytic. That is, Weierstrass's theorem says you can approximate a continuous function by polynomials, and in fact such polynomials can be obtained by getting an complete orthonormal set of polynomials and doing the usual projection technique. Yet Weierstrass's theorem does *not* say that you can do this by "freezing" coefficients like you do in computing a Taylor series.

Comment: Unique with respect to what property? You need an answer to that question first.